# Find all files in directory that have over 130 English characters or 43 asian characters

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to transfer files on my NAS, but I will get this error "The name of a file or a folder within an encrypted shared folder cannot exceed 143 English characters or 47 Asian (CJK) characters" is there a command in the shell to find every file that meets that?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, another copy is [on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/667959/108618).

Answer (score 0):

The actual limit is not characters but bytes. If the UTF-8 encoding is used, one CJK character usually needs 3 bytes and you get the same number as with English/Latin (47×3=141, 43×3=129).

This means the program doesn't actually need to count different types of characters (especially when they're mixed, e.g. `日本.doc`); it just needs to measure the raw length of the filename – which on most Linux systems is already stored as UTF-8 so no conversion is needed.

```
find ~/foo | perl -MFile::Basename -ne 'chomp($path = $_);
                                        print if length(basename($path)) > 140'
```

(If not told otherwise, Perl handles stdin input as raw bytes.)

Comment: That assumes file path don't contain newline characters. It would be better to use `find ~/foo -print0` and add the `-0` option of `perl` to work on NUL delimited records. See also the [unix.SE duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/667959) where I suggest ways using `find` alone.